# beautifulsoup misses the rest of the webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage, which is this one: [southafricatoday](https://southafricatoday.net/world-news/europe/damage-to-insured-property-during-yellow-vests-protests-soars-to-over-220mln/)

In this page, between the tags, there are empty tags like `<p><\p>`.
What I noticed is that, bs4 misses reading the rest of the page (after these empty tags).

[image]

All the tags after the red arrow are missed.

```
    import urllib.request as urllib2
    from urllib.request import Request
    import bs4
    url = 'https://southafricatoday.net/world-news/europe/damage-to-insured-property-during-yellow-vests-protests-soars-to-over-220mln/'  # row['link']
    page = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win32; Escape 4.8; U)'})
    page_content = urllib2.urlopen(page).read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_content, "html.parser")
    productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'td-post-content'})

    productDivs = productDivs[0].contents
    productDivs = [tag for tag in productDivs if not isinstance(tag, bs4.element.NavigableString)]
    x = productDivs[1]
    tags = x.findChildren(recursive=False) # check the tags here
```

Comment: To clarify, the request object (page_content) contains all the tags but BS4 seems to not find them when parsing?

Comment: @JacobKern, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this `html.parser`. To fix the issue, try changing `html.parser` either with `lxml` or with `html5lib`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://southafricatoday.net/world-news/europe/damage-to-insured-property-during-yellow-vests-protests-soars-to-over-220mln/'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for ptagContent in soup.find(itemprop="articleBody").find_all("p"):
    print(ptagContent.text)
```

Comment: Thanx @SIM, Yes I think it's because of "html.parse" parser.

Answer (score 1):

Ya that is odd. I'll have to look at the tags more closely as I'm about to step away, but just as a first go (so not the most eloquent or efficient), but you can get that first tag, then start looking for those next `<p>` tags, put them in a list, then join them to get the full output:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win32; Escape 4.8; U)'}
url = 'https://southafricatoday.net/world-news/europe/damage-to-insured-property-during-yellow-vests-protests-soars-to-over-220mln/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
productDivs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'td-post-content'})

article = ' '.join([ each.text.strip() for each in productDivs[0].find_next('p').find_next('p').parent.find_all('p') ])
```

**Output:**

```
print (article)
On Monday, the French Insurance Federation (FFA) reported 170 million euros in losses, however, this figure did not include losses caused by protests that took place on 16 March that were accompanied by serious disorder in the country. The newspaper Figaro reported that on Tuesday, Le Maire announced during hearings in the country’s parliament that overall losses, including from Saturday’s unrest, amounted to 200 million euros. READ MORE: France’s New Bid to Suppress Yellow Vest Protests Likely to ‘Help the Movement’ The wave of the yellow vests rallies — named after the obligatory attribute of French drivers — started in France in mid-November. The protests have been marked by violence and public disorder. While the French government ultimately abandoned plans to raise the fuel taxes that triggered the rallies in the first place, and introduced other measures to improve the country’s socioeconomic situation, the protests have continued and morphed into a broader movement against French President Emmanuel Macron’s economic policies and high living costs.  Sputnik News
South Africa Today – World News – Europe Join our mailing list to receive news every day Your email is safe with us. We hate spam too!
```